# Force windows WebView to load content in Portrait mode

Tags: xaml, unity-game-engine, windows-8.1

I have windows phone 8.1 game created on unity3d. It's support landscape orientation only. But I need a `WebView` in my game to load a page in portrait mode.
How to force `WebView` to load content in Portrait mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly what i need, but for now i use

```
DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;
```

when WebView load a page, and

```
DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
```

when close WebView and go back to game.